# "I'm happy when you're beside/s (of) me"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure

I have a doubt about the following sentence how it should be made correctly.

> "I'm happy when you're beside/s (of) me"

Beside or beside**s**, me or **of** me?

Comment: Don't forget the verb in the *when*-clause. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Now it make sense?:)

Comment: "Beside me", but I couldn't explain the grammar.  Perhaps it yet another idiom?

Comment: [Besides](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/besides) has a completely different meaning from [beside](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/beside). What did you find when you checked the dictionary?

Comment: I didn't check it on dictionary because I didn't imagine that they are two different words. I thought maybe it's a matter of plural and singular.

Answer (score 3):

*Besides*, according to [various dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?q=besides%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#dobs=besides), means "in addition", "as well as", or "other than", which is clearly not a meaning you want, so you need to use "beside", which has a primary meaning of "next to".

Then, *beside* is used here as a ["preposition of place"](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-prepositions-place.php), that is, a word indicating the position of something relative to something else.  As a preposition, it does not need an additional preposition ("of") to help it out; so "... when you're beside me" is correct.