# Could someone clarify the distinctions between 'beside,' 'besides,' 'aside from,' and 'apart from'?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

I often find myself confused when choosing the right word in various contexts. Are these words interchangeable, or do they have specific situations where they should be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I'm happy when you're beside/s (of) me"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122825/im-happy-when-youre-beside-s-of-me)

Comment: ...your second *(separate)* question is a duplicate of ["apart from" vs "other than" vs "aside from" vs "except for" vs "besides"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177619/apart-from-vs-other-than-vs-aside-from-vs-except-for-vs-besides)